# Creating a home page dynamically in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create all my pages using NextJs with the slugs/uri I get when fetching the data, however when trying to create the home page it says.

```
Error: The provided path `/` does not match the page: `/[slug]`.
```

[slug].tsx is located in the page folder. I removed the index.js since I would like to have the home page the same page layout as other pages.

Currently getting the static paths like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const allPages = await getAllPostsWithSlug();

  return {
    paths: allPages.edges.map(({ node }) => `${node.uri}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

The error I got makes sense, but I couldn't really find a solution to create my home page in the same page template.

Comment: Why do you need homepage as [slug]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-paths-key-required), you can use an optional catch-all route.

Name your page file `[[...slug]].js`, and then use something like the this for the `paths` prop in `getStaticPaths`:

```
paths: [
  { params: { slug: [] } },
  { params: { slug: ['foo'] } },
  { params: { slug: ['bar'] } },
]
```

FWIW - if you want to share components from the main template (i.e. header, nav, footer etc), I recommend using a custom `_app.js` page. If your homepage really is identical to your other pages, it might be worth re-visiting the design!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since `[...slug]` is not the same as `[slug]` as it grabs sub-paths as well, you can achieve a closer match using just `[slug].js` and adding a rewrite to your `next.config.js` like so:

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/homepage',
      },
    ]
  },
```

Then you handle the `homepage` slug as your homepage, just like any other CMS page or post.

(`/homepage` can be anything you want, e.g. `/index`)